# Oracle alternative to jsfiddle

Tags: oracle

Is there a service for oracle like jsfiddle is for javascript?

I need to test an oracle function (not against a database) and do not have an installation of oracle available.

Other features of jsfiddle would be nice, but my primary concern is just to be able to run simple functions and receive output.

Comment: If that was an option, I would not ask the question. I do not have access to an installation of oracle, or an internet connection good enough to download it, and I don't need an oracle installation, I only need to test a function. Also, installing oracle does not help with the extra features of jsfiddle which would allow me to colaborate quickly and easily with other developers.

Comment: /me upvoting the answer below.
jsfiddle runs nothing, your browser do, you don't need jsfiddle to run some Javascript while you need Oracle to run Oracle.

Comment: Ok, more like http://ideone.com/ than jsfiddle. I really don't think it is unreasonable question. Someone can have oracle installed on their server, I can send code via posting through web form, they can send result of executing my oracle code in a sandbox and return it on the web-page. Of course it can be done, I am asking if it has been done somewhere I can access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Oracle Apex](http://apex.oracle.com/i/index.html) gives you a demo/sandbox environment(featuring Oracle Apex & database) where you can test out whatever function that you want to test.

Plus you get to add collaborators so that works.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It's a hosted Apex/Oracle installation on apex.oracle.com. Local install isn't required

Comment: @Sathya: I missed the part in the question that said no *local* installation. I only saw **no** Oracle installation - which is clearly not possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I assumed no local installation/no access to a local Oracle install - maybe because I keep running into the same situation & have been using apex.oracle.com as an alternative

Answer (score 1):

Try http://sqlfiddle.com/.
It is not a daemon of speed, but works quite nice.